# How to convert timestamp to date MySQL

Tags: date, unix-timestamp

I'm following a guide on YouTube on how to make an Image Uploading website, by phpacademy, great guide. However, I'm trying to extend it a bit by displaying it in a human-readable way.

At the moment the `albums.timestamp` is saved on the database as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and results in `1348372089` for example. Now, if I want to convert these numbers into a regular date and time, such as `23-09-2012 05:00` (European standard), how should I proceed?

I have tried `DATE(albums.timestamp)` and `CONVERT(albums.timestamp, 120)`, `unix_timestamp(albums.timestamp)` as well as `CAST(120 as albums.timestamp)`, but none of them works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use FROM_UNIXTIME(str,format). 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

The second parameter will let you format the date string to your liking.

Formatting characters:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

`FROM_UNIXTIME(albums.timestamp)` works though!

Comment: While I'm at it. Does anyone know a nice way to convert this date (`2012-09-23 05:48:07` for example) to `23 sep 05:48`?
Is there a function already that can do this or do I have make on my own?

Comment: See my answer about formatting. Great job finding the correct function, btw