# Alter a MySQLi object?

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, timestamp

I'm currently working with an MVC pattern and have at the same time fallen in love with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in PHP; I create a `DateTime` object in the Model and form the date in the View with `$date->format('Y-m-d')`.

My question is if there's any way to alter the `MySQLi` object after a selection and change a MySQL timestamp column into an `DateTime` object?

My current solution is to loop through the `MySQLi` object and push every row to an array. It doesn't feel very sleek, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing that says you can't extend `mysqli` and/or `mysqli_stmt` objects to provide your own implementations for understanding DateTimes.

Comment: How would the extension look like? Performing a regular query, looping through the result and creating a new object?

Comment: `class mysql_with_datetime extends mysqli {  // your custom implementation }` I would have to give significant thought in terms of how to do something like this, as you would likely need to override significant portions of `mysqli`, `mysqli_stmt`, `mysqli_result`, etc. to make this work as expected. I would personally question what value you would get from the effort, as it is easy enough to simply instantiate DateTime objects as necessary to work with the returned data.

Comment: My guess is the better approach would be to look at your model and finding a way to flag certain fields as as datetime and have the model automatically instantiate the DateTime object for any fields marked as such.

Comment: Good point. My main reason was to keep the MVC solid, but maybe I have to make an exception and create the `DateTime` object in the View anyway, if there's no easy way to do it in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

If your reasoning is just to format the date, I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(table.column, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM table
```

I looked it up from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549685/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-mysql).

Haven't tested it, but, it should work out better than extending the MySQLi class for a little thing like date formats.

Comment: As I mentioned I'd prefer to maintain the MVC structure, so formating the date in the Model is off the table. :-)

Comment: Which rule is this one? (0.o) Or, I thought models manipulate data (CRUD)? Ah well, it's not what you're looking for. That's the only thing I could think of that would apply the date transformation to the entire data set without having to loop through the results or resort to a walk function.

Comment: Unix time is probably the only really universal way of going between one system and another for date/time data. And why would editing the Model entity to handle these transformation not be part of MVC? That's what the Model is there for. Handle the data, and talk to the data store.

Comment: Well, really it's a matter of preference. I'd say that the date format that's viewed by users belongs in the View. It's discussed [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126519/where-should-date-formatting-take-place-in-an-mvc-pattern), among other places.

Comment: True. It does make sense to save the formatting for the view as helpers, although it may make better use of server resources to pull the data formatted as needed. Since, if you were to store a locale designation in the URI, the View close to the last in the chain of command ( Router -> Controller -> Model -> View -> User -> Repeat ). So wouldn't it be more efficient for the Model to request data in the format it knows it needs? Correct me if my understanding is off...

Comment: That's a very good point. I want my functions to be reusable, and sometimes I need to show a relative date (eg. "Yesterday"), sometimes the full date and sometimes just the time. To maintain a well-performing code, usability and fairly correct MVC structure I think I'll create the `DateTime` object in the View. Thank you for keeping me on track. :-)